# Winning counting with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm building little game which will also have stats. Win times and things like that. So I made this html

```
<div id="stats">
    <h2>Stats</h2>
    <p>Win ratio: </p> <!-- Ignore this one -->
    <p><span id="wincount"></span> wins / <span id="lostcount"></span> losses</p>
</div>
```

And here is the Javascript code. I little bit shorted it so you can see only important things:

```
var wontimes = 0;
var losstime = 0;
function getResult(){
    var tie = "It's a tie!";
    var won = "You have won!";
    var lost = "You lost!";
    switch(user){
    case 1: // rock
        switch(npc){
        case 1: // rock
            result = tie;
            break;
        case 2: // paper
            result = lost;
            break;
        }
        break;
    case 2: // paper
        switch(npc){
        case 1: // rock
            result = won;
            break;
        case 2: // paper
            result = tie;
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
    document.getElementById("gameresult").innerHTML = result;
    if (result === won){
        return wontimes = wontimes++;
    } else if (result === lost){
        return losstime = losstime++;
    } else {
        console.log("Tie");
    }
    document.getElementById("wincount").innerHTML = wontimes;
    document.getElementById("lostcount").innerHTML = losstime;
}
```

Function getResult is called when user clicks button and it works, but there is a problem with it. After I click it. It tells me if I won and etc. But it doesn't count winning. I wanted to make it that everytime user win, wontimes get one plus and then it gets printed in `<span id="wincount"></span>`, it doesn't even show default 0 wins.

Can someone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you return from the function, the lines after are ignored.

Change

```
    return wontimes = wontimes++;
```

to

```
    wontimes++;
```

(and the same for `losstime`)

Note also that `wontimes++` is enough for incrementing a variable. If you do `wontimes = wontimes++`, you give to `wontimes` the value it had before the incrementing, which makes the whole useless.

Comment: Note that you might have analyzed what happens by debugging step by step in your browser. See for example [how it works with Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts).